# sqldependency onchange firing in asp.net but asp.net Controls are not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

sqldependency onchange firing in asp.net successfully and i am able to get Updated Data in Dataset but when it Binds the DataSet to Gridview it doesn't Refresh Itself.Furthermore No asp.net Page Life Cycle  event Fires when SqlDependency Event Fires.

Comment: Can you post some code, where you are handling updated data in dataset?

Comment: is there is any solution about this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the onchange event handler, you should be writing code to refresh the page or datagrid. 
It will not happen on its own. 
With SQL dependency, we are just mentioning a callback and that gets executed. Other than that, no event on asp side has fired to call page life cycle event handlers.

Comment: i am binding grid again but not refreshing moreover i also use a lable for testing purpose.i assign today date to lable in onchange method but no effect to label.

Comment: Can you try redirecting the user to some other page, does that work? If yes, you could refresh your page that way.

Comment: i have also tried this but .no Success.it generates error that response is not available in this context.

Comment: Does cross thread reference work for you? Something like this:
    'if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
      listView1.Invoke(new getEmployeeListDelegate(GetEmployeeList), listView1);'

    'GetEmployeeList(listView1);'
Assuming this function accepts the listview as a parameter and refreshes data in it

Comment: i also checked it.method like listview.invokeRequired and listView1.Invoke worked in desktop Project i am working in asp.net and asp.net listview control and other databinding controls have didn't such properties.so plz suggest me some alternate of invoke.